# Generating 3D pie chart using HIghchart and JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to generate a 3d pie chart using HighChart and the data is in JSON. It seem to only generate 2d  even though I have enabled 3D.

I am trying to generate a 3d pie chart like this
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/3d-pie

Can someone show me what i am missing on my code below.

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
   <script src="code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>

       $(document).ready(function() {
                var options = {
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'chart1',
                        type: 'pie',
                         options3d: {
                                     enabled: true,
                                     alpha: 15,
                                     beta: 15,
                                     depth: 50,
                                     viewDistance: 25
                               }
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: '',
    //                    x: -20 //center
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: '',
    //                    x: -20
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: []

                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        enabled: false,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Amount'
                        },
                        labels: {
    //                            formatter:function() {
    //                              return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0, '', ',');
    //                            }
    //                        ,enabled: false
                        }, 
                        plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 1,
                            color: '#808080'
                        }]
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                                this.x + ': $' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0, '', ',');
                        }
                    },
                    credits: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                    legend: {
    //                    layout: 'vertical',
    //                    align: 'right',
    //                    verticalAlign: 'top',
    //                    x: -10,
    //                    y: 100,
    //                    borderWidth: 0
                        enabled:false
                    },

                    series: []
                }

                $.getJSON("data1.json", function(json) {
                    options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
                    options.series[0] = json[1];
                    options.series[1] = json[2];
                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                });
            });
```

JSON DATA

```
[{
    "name": "",
    "data": ["Asset","Total Lending","Total Deposits","Brokered Deposits" ]
}, {
    "name": "First Republic Bank",
    "data": [48353330,38079817,37130929,1957317]
}, {
    "name": "Cathay Bank",
    "data": [11488897,8902674,8814629,497369]
}]
```

Comment: Did you include `<script src="code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>` ?

Comment: The code you posted works fine when I use the example 3d pie chart data from this page: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/3d-charts maybe this is something with the data or the json? here is a code pen https://codepen.io/shamshoum/pen/WOZVVm

Comment: Can you show a sample of the JSON you're generating?

Comment: I am not able to generate 3d but i am able to generate a 2D chart. I have included the highchart library and and json data. . You can show me any exmaple of pie chart as long as it uses json data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the 3d pie working in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/shamshoum/pen/WOZVVm). I have updated the pen with your json data.

The only thing missing in your options is:

```
plotOptions: {
  pie: {
    depth: 25
  }
}
```

If you look [here](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/3d-charts) you can see that some of the charts require not only the chart property to be sent but plotOptions as well.

> while some specific settings for different chart type can be found under plotOptions;

Comment: -Thanks That worked.. how do i show a selected pie and change the label slice to something else

Comment: You can see in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic/
How they format the data and how they format the datalabels in plotoptions.

Comment: {
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            y: 56.33
        }, {
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 24.03,
            sliced: true,
            selected: true
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            y: 10.38
        }, {
            name: 'Safari',
            y: 4.77
        }, {
            name: 'Opera',
            y: 0.91
        }, {
            name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
            y: 0.2
        }